# Displaying Date in Windows Store apps regarding Language

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store application I am displaying Date as Format(Sunday, March 09, 2013) Using `"{0:D}"`

I think Windows Default Language is **English (United Kingdom)**. In my app I want to display multi languages. If I Change the language, Suppose I changed to **English (United States)** the date is displaying as (**Sunday Sunday, March 09, 2013**).

```
loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(data.issues[four].date.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", null);
var date = loadedDate.DayOfWeek + " " + String.Format("{0:D}", loadedDate); 

txt4.Text = date;
```

If i try to change to any language it is displaying in same manner:
Any help it would be Helpful.

Comment: How did you change language?

Comment: I am Changing System Language Using Control Panel - Add Language.

Comment: Just *adding* a language doesn't switch it - did you also put the new language at the top of the list?

Comment: Yes.I am doing Like that only.
If it is Default language means it is okay..
If it is Change means it is going to be display as "Default Language Day of Week and Displaying Date(What I changed Language)"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet If default Language in my Windows OS is English(United Kingdom)..
If i change to any other language like  German,English (United States) it is working as Day of the week displaying as in Default Language as "Sunday" with the total date format which I want to display "Sunday, March 09, 2013" is in Language in which I changed.
I hope you can Understand now with my words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the guidelines "Test the app for the other languages" on MSDN page [Quickstart: Translating UI resources (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx):

> 1. Open the Control Panel, and select Clock, Language, and Region >
>      Language.
> 2. Note that the language that was displayed when you ran the
>      app is the top language listed that is English, German, or French. If your top language is not one of these three, the app falls back
>      to the next one on the list that the app supports.
> 3. If you do not have all three of these languages on your machine, add the missing
>      ones by clicking Add a language and adding them to the list.
> 4. To test the app with another language, select the language in the list and
>      click Move up until it is at the top. Then run the app.

And as I understand this is exactly what you tried to do. In your example you are using property [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx), which is not localization, because it is just a simple enum, so when you see Sunday, you actually see the value from [DayOfWeek enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx). To get localized day of week you can have different ways to find localized day of week, one of them:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(loadedDate.DayOfWeek)
```

Also you can use [DateTimeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.aspx) if you need more advanced way of formatting Date Time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But what the issue is I am getting the value of DayofWeek in default language. If I change my language to any other language it is displaying with both Dayof week names "Sunday(default language DayofWeek) Freitag(German DayofWeek) ,26.April 2013"

I hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Take a look on this page [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az4se3k1.aspx). Format 'D' is different in different languages. In some languages it includes day of week, in some does not.